# Missing method 'instance class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I've do not have any Nuget package installed. However, I'm getting the error below:

```
Error   2   
Error: Missing method 'instance class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<class NuGet.VisualStudio.IVsPackageMetadata> [Xamarin.TestCloud.Integration] NuGet.VisualStudio.IVsPackageInstallerServices::GetInstalledPackages(class [EnvDTE]EnvDTE.Project)' from class 'NuGet.VisualStudio.VsPackageInstallerServices'.       0   0
```

Also, I'm surprised here because it is showing Build Successful, but still showing above under error list.

I've also cross checked if I have installed any NuGet Package. And I'm not able to find any.

Anybody please give me some suggestion on this.

Comment: I'm getting this too, although using C++ projects. The output comes in the "Test Cloud" output window, and seems to appear at random (ie. not related to a build).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which went away after I updated Nuget through the visual studio menu

Tools > Extrensions and updates... > click on updates

from there I saw nuget had an update available. Run the update and restart visual studio.